# How to access web application in host running in virtual machine

Tags: java, ubuntu, wildfly, web-deployment

Currently I have setup an ubuntu server in virtual PC running in Windows 7.

Got it from http://developer-should-know.com/post/134394533957/how-to-install-wildfly-on-ubuntu

I configured JAVA and JBOSS related configuration and deployed a simple .war file(App).

Now I want to access it in my host pc i.e. in windows.
when I am pinging from host pc `ip: 192.168.64.129` its responding but when I put the ip in host browser its not accessing war file.

I know now i am lacking some more config issue.
How to solve it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default, wildfly listens on port 8080 (and the default http port of browsers is 80). So you could use

```
http://192.168.64.129:8080/
```

Alternatively, see the [WildFly Admin Guide - Configuring interfaces and ports](https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/WFLY9/Admin+Guide#AdminGuide-Configuringinterfacesandports) and change the http binding from 8080.

Comment: Ya after putting 8080 port it started but how to open the web app here App.war I put "http://192.168.64.129:8080/App" but displays 404-Not found. can you help a bit more.

Comment: That's really a different question, I suggest you connect to the http management interface and verify your deployment and/or check the logs.

Comment: Look for the log message that tells you what context was started, e.g.

`WFLYUT0021: Registered web context: '/clusterbench' for server 'default-server'`